# Get properties in LINQ inside group by clause

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to LINQ and I'm trying to group a list by two columns and use the count aggregate function but I'm not sure how to write this query properly.

Here is my class

```cs
public class Result
    { 
        public string? Type { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

First I read some data from a `dataTable` and add it to a list of `Result` without `Count` property

```cs
List<Result> list = new();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
    list.Add(new Result
                {
                    Type =row["Type"].ToString(),
                    Age = int.Parse(row["Age"].ToString()),
                    Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                    Description = row["Description"].ToString(),
                });
    }
```

Now I want to group by `Age` and `Type`, I wrote this query and it returns the right result but I'm wondering if there is another cleaner way to write this instead of using `Select().FirstOrDefault()` ?

```cs
IEnumerable<Result> myResult = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Age, x.Type }).Select(gr =>
             new Result
             {
                 Age = gr.Key.Age,
                 Type = gr.Key.Type,
                 Name = gr.Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Description = gr.Select(x => x.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Count = gr.Count()
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `FirstOrDefault()?.` to make it simple which use [Null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
IEnumerable<Result> myResult = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Age, x.Type }).Select(gr =>
     new Result
     {
         Age = gr.Key.Age,
         Type = gr.Key.Type,
         Name = gr.FirstOrDefault()?.Name,
         Description = gr.FirstOrDefault()?.Description,
         Count = gr.Count()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is much easier and simpler. Thank you!

Comment: remove `ToList()` :) it makes no sense to add it

Comment: @KamilBudziewski you're right, I'll remove it. Thanks.